# Custom "container" control with children using pure WinApi

Tags: c++, c, user-interface, winapi, controls

I would like to create a control (named HWND container) in a window (named HWND hwnd) that will hold other controls like a button (named HWND button) and an image (named HWND bitmap) avoiding the use of "static" standard class. It will contain some custom drawn controls whose messages will be handled in the main WndProc (I don't want to add another WndProc) and I would like at the same time to be able to call only once the function `ShowWindow(container, SW_HIDE)` to hide the control container and all the controls it holds.
Is this possible in plain WinApi (so no MFC or anything else)? What kind of control should I use?

Thanks,
LB

Comment: Rather than such a large description it would be better if you posted some code of your attempts. Try to make a minimal example of the problem. Then we can help you from there.

Answer (score 2):

I recommend to create a `"button"` window with style `BS_GROUPBOX`.

```
hButton = CreateWindow( "button", "group", WS_CHILD | WS_VISIBLE | BS_GROUPBOX, 0, 0, 0, 0, hWnd, NULL, hInstance, NULL );
```

`BS_GROUPBOX` creates a rectangle in which other controls can be grouped. The child controls are grouped by drawing a border around them. The window text is displayed in the upper-left corner.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I didn't mention (sorry) that I'll need to handle the messages for the controls children of this child control that contains them. I mean I'll have to code the command for buttons or the code for making a custom progress bar increment and so on... Will that be possible using a button BS_GROUPBOX? Will I be able to paint it without a rectangle, if I'll need it? Or will it forcefully look like another common button? Thanks again for the time spent reading and replying :)

Comment: Thanks again. What about this button's children controls? Will I receive the messages for an eventual custom button child of this control in the mai WndProc or I'll have to write another processing function?

Comment: Sorry for my ignorance but I couldn't understand what you meant... Can you explain with an example? Let's say I have the hwnd which is my main window, hwnd_button_bsgroup which is the button that you described, child of hwnd and another control hwnd_button_child child of hwnd_button_bsgroup.

Comment: So if I have understood, you're basically saying I have to put hwnd_button_bsgroup as hwnd's child and also hwnd_button_child as hwnd's child if I want to keep on having only one WndProc (I was trying to avoid multiple processing procedures)... Right?